# How can I use reflection to change properties with missing setters?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, getter

I have two classes with property getters only

```
public class A 
{
    public A(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; set;}
    public string Data { get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public B(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
```

They are different in shape but share some of the same property names and types.
How can I copy values when they only have getters?

This is a typical scenario when I send an object as a constructor parameter to extract values from in the new object. Then I need to copy values one by one. This can produce lots of code and is hard to maintain.

Can this be made simpler? Is there a way to use reflection to copy objects when the target only has getter properties?

Comment: What the point of having auto-implemented properties without even private setter? How such object should be used without reflection magic?

Comment: It is allowed in the latest version of C#, but it can only be set in the constructor. Read-only when created.

Comment: agree, but you are setting only `Name` in constructor. So there is no ordinal way to setup `Value` and `Data`

Comment: Those were added in a hurry :)  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a helper function that copies two objects where the target object only has property getters.

Try this;

```
public static void CopyItem<U, T>(U source, T target)
{
    // Need a way to rename the backing-field name to the property Name ("<A>k__BackingField" => "A")
    Func<string, string> renameBackingField = key => new string(key.Skip(1).Take(key.IndexOf('>') - 1).ToArray());

    // Get public source properties (change BindingFlags if you need to copy private memebers as well)
    var sourceProperties = source.GetType().GetProperties().ToDictionary(item => item.Name);
    // Get "missing" property setter's backing field
    var targetFields = typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetField).ToDictionary(item => renameBackingField(item.Name));

    // Copy properties where target name matches the source property name
    foreach(var sourceProperty in sourceProperties)
    {
        if (targetFields.ContainsKey(sourceProperty.Key) == false)
            continue; // No match. skip

        var sourceValue = sourceProperty.Value.GetValue(source);
        targetFields[sourceProperty.Key].SetValue(target, sourceValue);
    }
}
```

This is a generic description. You will probably want to check the property and field data types as well before you copy the value to prevent exceptions. Both name and data type should match.

Use CopyItem to copy matching source properties in a constructor;

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(SomeSourceClass source)
    {
        Helper.CopyItem(source, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that this will work? What if `T` contains more than one nomal private field? In that case your helper method will return more than one time an empty string that will result in duplicate key exception. Maybe there should be a `where` clause that filters for backing fields. BTW: it looks like this solution will also work after running constructor (can't test it). If that's true you'll change properties that should be immutable. And last: don't forget performance.

Comment: This does probably not cover all scenarios. Like when you mix auto-properties with getters only with custom backing fields. Then you can have some suprises, of course. Especially when your backing-fields have other names than your properties. But in most cases this would work. I spent some time to find a way to set properties with getters only. Just wanted to share :)